# C++ having issue with my variable going back to zero

Tags: c++, curly-braces

Having a problem with the value the user score not going back to 0 after the program is done i think I messed up the brackets somewhere and help will be highly appreciated.

the point of this code is to make a simple text based c++ program that will have a series of three menus and will add to a score after each menu

```
            int main()
            {







                //declare and initialize variables


                int menuChoice = 0, highscore = 0, race = 0, weapon = 0, userscore = 0, enemy = 0, randomscore = 0, enemydamage = 0, enemydamage1 = 0, enemydamage2 = 0 ;
                string username, username1 ;


                srand(time(NULL)) ;
                ifstream infile ;
                ofstream outfile ;


            //intro

                    cout<<"------------------Welcome to the Arena Get ready to Fight------------------\n\n" ;                                             



                //prompt for username
                cout<<"Please tell me your First Name:   "; 
                cin>>username ; 

                cout<<"\n\n" ; 

                //display menu 

            do
            {

                cout<<"Hello "<<username<<endl ; 
                cout<<"Please choose from the following menu:\n";
                cout<<"1) See Rules\n2) Play Game\n3) Quit\n";


            //prompt for menu choice
            cout<<"Enter your choice here: ";
                cin>>menuChoice;



                //switch structure
                switch(menuChoice)
                {
                    case 1:
                    //display rules

                    cout<<"Welcome to the Arena "<<username<<"you will be given 3 choices which will let you choose your race, weapon, and enemy. Eacho choice has its own point value which might be random or a fixed number the goal is to surive and not have you health hit 0\n\n" ;       

                    break;

                    case 2: 
                    //Game Intro

                    cout<<"Welcome "<<username<<" time to fight!!!!!!\n" ;      

                    randomscore = rand()%100 + 1 ;      

                    do
                    {   
                    //display menu
                    cout<<"Please choose a Race\n";
                    cout<<"1) Elf\n2) Dwarf\n3) HUman\n";


                    //Prompt user to choose race        
                    cout<<"Enter your choice here: ";
                    cin>>race;
                    if (race < 1 || race > 3) 
                    {
                    cout<<"Invalid. Must be a Valid Menu Choice between 1-3.\n\n";
                    }       
                    }
                    while(race < 1 || race > 3) ;


                    {
                    if ( race == 1)
                    {    
                     userscore += 100 ;
                    }
                    else if (race == 2 )
                    {
                        userscore += 200 ;
                        }
                    else {
                        userscore += randomscore;
                    }
                    }

                        {
                            //display userscore


                            cout<<"Nice Choice "<<username<<" your current score is "<<userscore<<endl; 
                        }

                    do
                    {
                    //menu 2 
                    cout<<"Please choose a Weapon\n";
                    cout<<"1) Sword\n2) Axe\n3) Bow\n";



                    //prompt user to choose a weapon 
                    cout<<"Enter your choice here: ";
                    cin>>weapon;
                    if(weapon < 1 || weapon > 3)            
                        {
                        cout<<"Invalid. Must be a Valid Menu Choice between 1-3.\n\n";
                    }
                    }       
                while(weapon < 1 || weapon > 3) ;

                        {           
                        if (weapon == 1)
                        {
                            userscore += 60 ; 
                            }
                        else if (weapon == 2)
                        {
                        userscore += randomscore ; 
                        }   
                        else 
                        {           
                        (userscore += 100) ;
                        }
                        }
                    {
                        //display userscore

                        cout<<"Hope that can help you "<<username<<" your current score is "<<userscore<<endl;


                    }   
                    {
                    //menu 3
                    enemydamage = rand()%100 + 1    ;
                    enemydamage1 = rand()%200 + 1   ;
                    enemydamage2 = rand()%50 + 30   ;
                    }

                    do
                    {
                    cout<<"Please choose a Enemy\n";
                    cout<<"1) Orc\n2) Troll\n3) Goblin\n";



                    //prompt user to choose a enemy 
                    cout<<"Enter your choice here: ";
                    cin>>enemy; 
                    if(enemy < 1 || enemy > 3)
                    {
                    cout<<"Invalid. Must be a Valid Menu Choice between 1-3.\n\n";
                    }
                    }       
                    while(enemy < 1 || enemy > 3) ;





                {
                    if ( enemy == 1 )
                    {
                        userscore -= enemydamage ;
                        }
                    else if  ( enemy == 2 )
                        {
                        userscore -= enemydamage1 ;
                        }
                    else
                        {
                        userscore -= enemydamage2 ;
                        }


                {
                    cout<<"Its time "<<username<<" to show you your score\n\n"; 


                    }
                    }
                        {           
                        infile.open("highscore.txt", ios::in);  
                        infile>>username1>>highscore ;
                        infile.close() ; 
                        }


                    {       
                        if
                        (userscore < 0 )    
                        {
                            //display you are dead try again
                            cout<<"Your Are dead try again\n" ; 
                        }
                    else if (userscore < highscore) 
                        {
                        //display userscore
                        cout<<"Nice Job!! "<<username<<" but you didn't beat the High Score, your final score is "<<userscore<<endl;
                        }
                    else

                        {

                        outfile.open("highscore.txt", ios::out) ;
                        outfile<<username<<"\t"<<userscore ;
                        outfile.close();
                        cout<<"Nice Job Your Final Score is "<<userscore<<" and that beats the High Score\n\n";
                        }
                        }
                        break; 



                        case 3: //Dislpay program Exit
                        cout<<"Have a Nice Day!!\n\n"  ;
                        break;

                        default: 

                        cout<<"Invalid. You must choose 1 - 3 from the menu.\n\n"  ;


                }
                }

                while(menuChoice !=3) ;


             return 0;
            }
```

Comment: Your use of formatting is rather *unpredictable*.  This makes your code awfully hard to read.

Comment: Way too much code to read, but I wouldn't be surprised if you're missing a `userscore = 0;` inside the loop.

Comment: Yeah your code is really bad... clean it up. And what is it that you want? What do you mean you want the score to be 0 after the program is done?  The score is what it is when the program is done. Do you mean after each 'Play' you want everything to reset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reset the variable:

```
userscore = 0;
```

either at the start of do statement or before the end of while statement. This will solve your problem.